# Using Modulus operator in for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, modulus

I've been trying to get the output to print that after every 6 numbers, a newline is added. However, it's not working as intended. If user enters 9 in the main function, it should print out:

```
21    13    8     5     3     2  
1     1     0
```

but instead is printing

```
21   13
8     5    3    2    1    1
0
```

Almost correct but not quite. How do I go about fixing this? I'm not sure if it's because of my indexing or if I'm incorrectly using the modulus operator. Thank you!

My code:

```
void Fibonacci(int length)
{

    int arr[20] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21,
                   34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377,
                    610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181};

    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {

        if (i % 6 == 0 )
        {

           cout<<endl;

        }
        cout<<setw(5)<<arr[i];

    }
    cout<<endl;
```

Comment: This is working exactly as you'd expect. Your index variable `i` is starting at 20 and counting down. Do you expect 18, the second count you're hitting, to not be a modulus of 6? You need to fix up your math here or use a 0..N based index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    cout<<setw(5)<<arr[i];

    if (((length - 1 - i) % 6 == 5)
    {
       cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

---

Or, as **@tadman** suggested,

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    cout<<setw(5)<<arr[length - 1 - i];

    if (i % 6 == 5)
    {
       cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)` might be easier, then referencing `arr[length-1-i]` instead.

Comment: @tadman It makes the `for` loop to look more canonical, but IMO somehow changes semantics. In the first case, `i` means the working index, and `length-1-i` is rather a technical value to find where to put `endl`. In the second case, it is vice versa. Anyway, thank you! I updated the answer.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I find counting backwards like that is a recipe for lots of off-by-one errors. Showing them both shows the benefits and drawbacks of each approach. Nice!

Comment: Wow guys thank you so much.@AlexD and @tadman It works perfectly, now I'm a little confused on that syntax. would one of you guys do me one more favor and just explain the idea of length - 1 - i. I'm sorry, I just don't wanna utilize it without trying understanding the concept.

Comment: @BobRoss In the first case, `i` is the index of the element "from the left end of array" (if I can use such terms), and `k = length-1-i` is the index of the element from the right end. So, `i` is used to point at what to print, and `k` is used to decide where to put `endl`. In the second case it is vice versa.